# How to calculate the number of total questions of a user if you have his accept rates?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

It recently happened to me:

My original accept rate 
on one of the stackexchange websites was 62% , but after going back to an old question and accepting an answer there- it got raised to 65%.

So is there a way to find the total number of questions asked by me?

I've come up with this:

original accepted answers=*x*

total questions answered=*y*  [ignoring the unanswered ones, because that's what I                      think stackexchange's algorithm does]

so *x/y=62*

On accepting an answer it got raised to 65, so

*(x+1)/y=65*

Is it right? It gave me a fraction less than 1.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with units.  $x$ and $y$ are whole numbers, but $62$ and $65$ are percentages and should be expressed as $0.62$ and $0.65$.  Also you lost something when you wrote *x+1/=65*.  Maybe you started with $(x+1)/y=65$ and later read it as $x+(1/y)=65$?

You have $\frac xy=0.62$ and $\frac {x+1}y=0.65$.  Subtracting we get $\frac 1y=0.03$, so $y=\frac {100}3$.  Since $y$ must be a whole number, there must be some rounding on the percentages.  Taking $y=33$ would give $x=20.46$ in the first equation.  You can play with values nearby to see if you can find an $x$ that is closer to a whole number.  This shows the inaccuracy of the subtraction-you can think we really got $y = 0.03 \pm 0.01$ which is a large possible error.

Comment: How'd you get `y=0.03±0.01`? Don't understand where you got the 0.01 from?

Comment: @Ghost:  I got it because I assume the $0.65$ is rounded to two decimals and could really be anywhere between $0.645$ and $0.655$.  Similarly the $0.62$ is really somewhere between $0.615$ and $0.625$.  Subtracting $0.655-0.615$ gives $0.04$, while taking the other ends gets $0.02$

Comment: @ Ross Millikan sorry I dont really understand the concept- `0.65` is a percentage, why even take a range between `0.645 and 0.655`

Comment: @Ghost:  Suppose you had accepted $2$ out of $3$ questions.  The correct percentage would be $66.66666\ldots \%$  The site would probably round that to $67\%$ (at least all the percentages I have seen are whole numbers).  If you had accepted $337$ out of $500$ the correct percentage would be $67.4\%$ but would probably be reported as $67\%$ as well.